# How do I pair a second smartcard to my MacBook?

Tags: catalina, smart-card

I have a couple smartcards issued by my employer. Each is for a different account. When I plugged one in to my MacBook running Catalina (10.15.3) for the first time I was prompted to pair it. I think. I don't really recall. For all I know I might have ran a program or something. Regardless, it's been a while and I don't recall.

I now want to pair the second smartcard. When I plug it in, I'm not being prompted to pair it. Is there a program I can run manually to do this or some other way to force the pairing prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: `sc_auth` using various options. It also has the `pairing_ui` option to force the dialog box to pop up.